# Firefox loses JSP session bean changes on refresh

Tags: jsp, firefox, javabeans

While my IE, Safari, and Chrome have no problem with it, Firefox (in this case 15.0) loses session bean changes on refresh. I can tell that it's applying the Java code, but it is not persisting the object properly. Here is a simple incrementing JSP to try it out on.

```
<jsp:useBean id="point" class="java.awt.Point" scope="session"/>
<%point.setLocation(point.getX()+1, 0);%>
<%=(int)point.getX()%>
```

Comment: It increments in scope="application" but I don't understand why it does nothing for scope="session". Is it a browser setting?

Comment: I am noticing that I am getting a new JSESSIONID on every load. Why doesn't it consider it to be the same session?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. It was generating new sessions, because that browser was set to deny cookies. Rookie mistake, chalked to experience.